# Javascript Function doesn't work with different attribute id or name format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list with default values. I have a need to empty the list and append new list values to the drop down. Below function works fine when the drop down attribute id is in simple format like this: `CCManager`.

For my application I need to have the attribute id as `[1].CCManager`, `[2].CCManager` etc. I tried different approaches to get the below function working for the id name, but failed.

The attribute name is dynamically generated with a suffix, that's the reason I have to work with this format.

```js
function load123(obj) {
    var ccmDDL = $('#CCManager');
    ccmDDL.empty();
    ccmDDL.append($('<option />', {
        value: '2222',
        text: 'Appended'
    }));
}
```

Below is the select drop down I am using. When I select a product from first drop down list, I would query the database with the selected product and retrieve Fiscal year values related to the product dynamically and populate the fiscal year drop down list.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="[0].Product" onchange="load123(this);">
            <option value="15>Corporate HQ</option>
            <option value="16">Data Campaign</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="[0].FISCAL_YEAR">
        </select>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="[1].Product" onchange="load123(this);">
            <option value="15>Corporate HQ</option>
            <option value="16">Data Campaign</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="[1].FISCAL_YEAR">
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What are the different approaches you have tried?

Comment: are you using `[1].CCManager` as the `id` for the tag? Like `<select id="[1].CCManager">`?

Comment: yes I am using "[1].CCManager" as the ID.

Comment: add the html code too. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Starts with 1,2,3 then after the method has 4,5,6.

```js
var newManagers = [4, 5, 6];

function load123() {
    var ccmDDL = $('#CCManager');
    ccmDDL.empty();
    for(newManager in newManagers)
    {
      ccmDDL.append($('<option />', { value: 'newManager', text: newManagers[newManager] + ' Manager', id: "["+newManagers[newManager]+"].CCManager" }));
    }
}

load123();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="CCManager">
  <option value="1" id="[1].CCManager">1 Manager</option>
  <option value="2" id="[2].CCManager">2 Manager</option>
  <option value="3" id="[3].CCManager">3 Manager</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're using `id="[1].CCManager"` on the tag. You can target it in jQuery using the attribute selector

```js
var ccmDDL = $('select[id="[1].CCManager"]');
ccmDDL.empty();
ccmDDL.append($("<option />", { value: "2222", text: "Appended" }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="[1].CCManager"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael and all who jumped in. This statement resolved my issue. var ccmDDL = $('select[id="[1].CCManager"]');   You guys are great!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery 'Attribute Ends with' selector if your dropdown ids are dynamically generated. - https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

```js
$(function(){
console.log($("select[id$='CCManager']").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="[1].CCManager"></select>
<select id="[2].CCManager"></select>
<select id="[3].CCManager"></select>
```